# How to use webpack-hot-middleware in multiple entries with vue

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I'm using `webpack-hot-middleware` in multiple entries, I give each entry a path in the plugin config and I can see in the browser console `[HMR] connected`. When I update my file I see the webpack rebuild but never reload at all.

Some of my config looks like this:

```
const devMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const hotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
const app = express();
const webpackConfig = require(`../configs/webpack.dev.conf.js`);

dirs.forEach(function(dir, index) {
    let _config = new webpackConfig(dir);

    app.use(devMiddleware(webpack(_config), {
        publicPath: _config.output.publicPath
    }));
    app.use(hotMiddleware(webpack(_config), {
        path: `/${dir}/__webpack_hmr`
    }));
});

function getDirs(_dir) {
    return fs.readdirSync(_dir)
        .filter((_file) => {
            return fs.statSync(path.join(_dir, _file)).isDirectory()
        })
}
```

And in my `webpack.dev.conf.js`:

```
module.exports = function (dir) {
    /* some other config here */
    webEntry.push(`webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&path=/${dir}/__webpack_hmr`);

    const webConfig = {
        entry: webEntry,
        output: {
            path: helper.rootNode('./dist', dir),
            filename: '[name].web.js',
            publicPath: `/${dir}`
        },
    /* some other config here */
    }

    return webConfig;
}
```

Also I add `new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()` in my plugin list.

Every time I change my code I can see `webpack-dev-middleware` recompile but I can never see a reload after my changes after a `[HMR] connected` in my browser console. I'm using this in my vue project that each component or view is a single-file-components. It works nomally with the help of vue-loader.

Is it anything wrong with my config ? Thanks for your help in advance.